# Como Editar Los Campos de Una tabla En Php?

Tags: php, mysql

Hola queridos amigos soy nuevo en esto de php y no se como hacer para poder editar los datos de mi base de datos, ya he hecho un script para poder ver los resultados de la tabla que se llama "users" y tiene los campos "id", "username", "email" y "gold" tiene estos 4 campos, me gustaria saber que tengo que añadirle a mi codigo de script para poder editarlos directamente desde mi script, este es el codigo de mi script:

```
<?php 

    $conexion=mysqli_connect('shareddb-****.net','****','1235***689','monkeydb');

 ?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>GreasyMonkey Foro</title>
</head>
<body>

<br>

    <table border="1" >
        <tr>
            <td>id</td>
            <td>username</td>
            <td>email</td>
            <td>gold</td>
                
        </tr>

        <?php 
        $sql="SELECT * from users";
        $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
        while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
         ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $mostrar['id'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $mostrar['username'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $mostrar['email'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $mostrar['gold'] ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php 
    }
     ?>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

si alguien me podria ayudar para que mi script pueda editar los registros de esta tabla le estaria muy agradecido, feliz noche y saludos para todos! =)

Comment: Hola! Esconde los datos sensibles de tu conexión a tu base de datos, ya que estas expuesto a practicas maliciosas al ponerlas publicas.

Comment: Hola, primero edita el post y remplaza los datos de tu conexión, te estas exponiendo con eso. Lo otro es que yo he logrado hacerlo pero con un validador, es decir, si quiero editar el email o lo que sea como en tu caso, el usuario deberá introducir el id como en tu caso y de esa manera estará seguro de editar el campo, si lo deseas te hago la respuesta, saludos

Comment: Hola Ricardo y Cristian muchas gracias por ayudarme es que necesito este codigo para poder editar a mis usuarios desde este script y si Cristian tu ayuda me serviria de mucho! muchas gracias! =)

Comment: Para editar necesitas colocar dentro de php código SQL relacionado a un UPDATE, te aconsejo que veas un CRUD sencillo en Youtube, con ello aclararás dudas que ni siquiera sabes que puedes tener ahora.

Comment: Hola gracias luis lo estoy buscando pero casi todos son de conexiones a php

Comment: Como dice @LuisAlfredoSerranoDíaz , te recomiendo que veas como se hace un CRUD (independiente que elijas uno muy simple, luego con el tiempo lo haces mas robusto). Una de las primera cosas que debes hacer es preparar la interfaz de ingreso y actualización de datos, mediante el uso de formularios y en consecuencia programar los script php que recibirán, validaran y almacenaran tus datos.